# Steam with a computer using 2 monitors

Tags: steam, monitor

I have 2 monitors, and every time that i run a game from steam, it runs in the wrong monitor. Can I tell steam in which of the monitors to use the full screen mode?

Thanks

Comment: I think Steam uses the "main" monitor to run games in. Check your display settings and make sure your "main" monitor is listed as "1".

Answer (score 3):

Since this thread still has no accepted answer:

A simple solution with Ubuntu 18.04 and possibly any later version that uses Gnome desktop is to just start the game (in full-screen mode). Then press the "Super/Windows" key and just drag and drop the game to whatever monitor you want to play on.

No need for "Big Picture" mode or anything at all.

Comment: I'll note this only works with some games.

Answer (score 2):

My solution: Launch Steam in "Big Picture" mode (click the controller icon in the top right), then wait for it to open. After it loads, press the "Super"/"Window" key (in between ctrl and alt) to show all open windows, then click & hold on Steam and drag it to the monitor you want to play on. When you launch the game, it will open on the same desktop/monitor.

I remember seeing an option to choose the output monitor at one point, but I just checked again and I cannot find it. That option may have been in the Windows Steam client...

Comment: I cannot replicate this on Ubuntu 17.04.  Can you confirm this still works?

Comment: Does not works.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set the second screen as the main screen.

Comment: Can you add details?  How would they do this?

Comment: it depends on what ubuntu do you have @StephenOstermiller